Push notification IOS expo SDK upgrade from 48 to 50 Problems with App store builld
I am getting a push notification on actual device that is a development build and push notifications are working fine both when sending and receiving and using expo push notification tool.  But, when I submit the app to the app store and test on testflight, No expo token is generated. It was working fine with expo sdk 48 but I recently upgraded to sdk 50 and now the token is not being generated.
 let token;
 let projectId;

 if (Platform.OS === "android") {
   await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
     name: "default",
     importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
     vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
     lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
   });
 }

 if (Device.isDevice) {
   const { status: existingStatus } =
     await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
   let finalStatus = existingStatus;
   if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
     const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
     finalStatus = status;
   }
   if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
     alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
     return;
   }
   projectId = Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId;

   token = (
     await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
       projectId: projectId,
     })
   ).data;
   console.warn("projectId", projectId);
   console.log("token", token);
   console.log("projectId", projectId);
 } else {
   alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
 }

 return token;
} ````
. Does anyone know what the problem can be?

